# Tensorflow tf.cond and multiline lambdas

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm playing around with `tf.cond` and `tf.while_loop`. I have the following code:

```
def cond_loop_test(t1, num_steps):
    def cond(i, t1, t2, t3, t4):
        return tf.less(i, num_steps)

    def body(i, t1, t2, t3, t4):
        t3, t4 = t3+1, t4+1

        def last_step(t1, t2):
            t1 = t1+2
            t2 = t2+2
            def f1(): return t1, t2
            return f1

        def other_steps(t1, t2):
            t1 = t1+1
            t2 = t2+1
            def f2(): return t1, t2
            return f2

        tf.cond(tf.equal(i+1, num_steps), last_step(t1, t2), other_steps(t1, t2))

        return [tf.add(i, 1), t1, t2, t3, t4]

    return tf.while_loop(cond, body, [0,
                                      t1,
                                      tf.zeros_like(t1),
                                      tf.zeros_like(5),
                                      tf.zeros_like(5)])

t1 = tf.ones(5)
num_steps = tf.constant(5)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    cond_loop = cond_loop_test(t1, num_steps)
    print(sess.run(cond_loop))
```

The code basically runs 5 loops with a simple conditional which should run different code at different stage during the loop execution of the graph.

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
[5, array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), 5, 5]
```

As you can see tensors `t1` and `t2` do not get modified despite their being modified inside functions `last_step` and `other_steps` - these functions return no-argument function which are required by `tf.cond`.

What I would expect is something like this:

```
[5, array([8., 8.,8., 8., 8.], dtype=float32), array([7., 7., 7., 7., 7.], dtype=float32), 5, 5]
```

Basically both `t1` and `t2` would be incremented 4 times and then added 2 in the last iteration loop.

**Note:** I can't use multiline lambda here because if I did python would cry about `UnboundLocalError: local variable  referenced before assignment`, hence the ugly python hack which merely returns zero-arg function which returns the modified tensors (kinda getting used to hacks in this language at this point).

Can someone help me out understanding why aren't tensors `t1` and `t2` modified in the above code? As you can see tensors `t3` and `t4` do get modified correctly, alas they're not modified inside the conditional functions.

Comment: It looks like you just need to assign to `t1` and `t2` the result of the `cond` in `body`? But I'd also note that only ops _created_ inside a `lambda` passed to `cond` have conditional execution. Capturing them in a closure means they always get executed. In this case none of the ops are stateful, so it won't affect the result.

Comment: You are on the money here @AllenLavoie! I tested your suggestion and it does seem to work - it also makes sense why. I should have thought of that earleir